# Why is MongoDB unable to populate() on this query?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections, defined as follows:

**user.model.ts**

```js
import { Schema, model, Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from './interfaces';

// Create model
const UserSchema = new Schema<User>({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  passDigest: { type: String, required: true },
  verified: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  codes: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'GameCode' },
  orders: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Order' } // This will just be an array of IDs.
});

// Compile and export
export const UserModel: Model<User> = model<User>('User', UserSchema);
```

**confirmation.model.ts**

```js
import { Schema, model, Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Confirmation } from './interfaces';

const ConfSchema = new Schema<Confirmation>({
  confNumber: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  verified: { type: Boolean, required: true }
})

export const ConfModel: Model<Confirmation> = model<Confirmation>('Confirmation', ConfSchema);
```

Given this setup, I should (theoretically) be able to get a document from the Confirmation collection and populate the associated User using that reference according to all documentation that I have read.

However, when I fetch a document from the Confirmation collection and attempt to populate (in an Express route handler function), this is not the case:

```js
// POST /users/confirm
//
// { confId: String, login: String, password: String }
export const confirmUser: RequestHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const currentConf = await ConfModel.findById(req.body.confId).populate('User');
    res.send(currentConf);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(`Unable to complete user confirmation request: ${err}`);
  }
}
```

I am able to fetch a document, but instead of population happening, the `user` property is never replaced with the associated User document.

Confirmation document (stored in MongoDB Atlas):

[image: Confirmation Document]

User document (also stored in Atlas):

[image: User Document]

I am very confused, because according to the documentation, this should be working.  As far as I'm aware, you shouldn't need to do anything else other than:

1. Define both schemas/models
2. Define a reference in the schema that will receive the population, making sure to match the **name** of the model you're wanting to populate
3. Perform your query (in my case, `ConfModel.findById` to fetch a single record by _id)
4. Do a `.populate()` on that query, passing the same name that you used before.

Does this have anything to do with using async/await?  Do I need to be using `.exec()`?  I've also tried using `ConfModel.findById(...).populate('User').exec(...)` to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any advice, I'm really lost here, and it has to be something really simple that I'm overlooking.

Comment: populate('user') not populate('User')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must populate a field of confirmation.model, which is `user` not `User`,

so use `.populate('user')` not `populate('User')`

Comment: Thanks again, worked perfectly after the fix.   I was misreading docs apparently.